# Can't revivify a Panzer Vulpaphyla

Tags: warframe

I'm trying to revivify a *Panzer Vulpaphyla* in the game *Warframe* by going to Son, but the game won't let me.

I go to Son's menu and click on *Panzer Vulpaphyla*, then I choose a random mutagen and antigen I have. When I go to preview, it says `"PARTS NOT OWNED"`.

Is this because the game will show the *Panzer Vulpaphyla* in Son's menu even if you haven't actually saved one, or is there a different reason this may be happening? Would I have to end up searching for a *Panzer Vulpaphyla*?

On a side note, I heard that you can only find a *Panzer Vulpaphyla* during Fass's reign over Deimos. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on each one of the items you need to make a Vulpaphyla, it should show a checkmark (and number if you have more than one) next to the ones you have.

The Warframe wiki confirms that Panzer Vulpaphyla only appear during Fass, with Crescent being its Vome equivalent; Sly is the common version for both time periods.

Panzer appear both in the wild and when doing conservation during Fass.  If you're doing Conservation, Vulpaphyla Pheromone Gland (purchasable from Son for 150 Entrati Standing) makes Panzer (and Crescent) more common.